# Merge two Dataframe with columns name differents

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DateFrame with values and number of rows different. All Index values in second DateFrame is in the first, so, I need a DateFrame with the same number of rows that the second DateFrame and all data of both  DateFrames.

Example

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "C"], data=[['a1' , 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2',  'b2', 'c2'], ['a3',  'b3', 'c3']], index=[1,2,3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["D", "E"], data=[['d2' , 'e2'], ['d3' , 'e3']], index=[2,3])
print (df1)
print (df2)

Out:
        A   B   C
    1  a1  b1  c1
    2  a2  b2  c2
    3  a3  b3  c3

        D   E
    2  d2  e2
    3  d3  e3
```

I want:

```
      A   B    C   D   E
2    a2  b2   c2   d2  e2 
3    a3  b3   c3   d3  e3
```

I try this:

```
merge = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on=df1.index, right_on=df2.index)
```

But I receive an error:

> IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

Note: Not all index in df1 are in df2 but all index in df2 are in df1.

Comment: instead of `left_on=...` and `right_on=...` have you tried `left_index=True` and `right_index=True`?

Comment: `merge = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Comment: Thanks, its works !!!